# SQL : return value in required format

Tags: sql, mysql

```
select myvalue from mytable where id=1;
```

it return a value of 10 digits(`Ex: 1234567890`).
I want these value in `1234.56.7890` format as return value.

means **myvalue** can return value in required format and not in stored format.

Can anyone help me.
You ideas are very wellcome

Comment: What is the datatype of the myvalue column?

Comment: myvalue column contains long value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly confusing alternative:

```
SELECT REVERSE(
  INSERT(
    INSERT(REVERSE(1234567890), 5, 0, '.'),
      8, 0, '.')) AS formatted;

+--------------+
| formatted    |
+--------------+
| 1234.56.7890 |
+--------------+
```

This works even for shorter numbers - e.g. 123.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function.

Comment: I want add two decimal between my values.

Answer (score 0):

It is littlebit expensive command. but it will work if your decimal position is fixed and myvalue is always going to be 10 digits

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(10),myvalue),4) + '.' +
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10),myvalue),5,2) + '.' +
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10),myvalue),7,4)
```